# List of Top brands in any category or subcategory

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008, I urgently need sql query or stored procedure to display top brands in any category or sub-category. For example if I pass IdCategory=2, the result set should display top brands in Electronics by performing products count on idCategory=2 as well as its sub categories and sub-sub-categories. If I pass IdCategory=38, the result should display top brands in Phones & Mobile Devices as well as Mobile Phones. I hope I am able to clear my requirement.

Here are the tables in my database.

**Categories**

```
IdCategory    CategoryName              ParentCategoryId
---------------------------------------------------------
1             Appliances                Null
2             Electronics               Null
38            Phones & Mobile Devices   2
39            Cameras & Photography     2
115           Mobile Phones             38
121           Digital Cameras           39
```

**Brands**

```
IdBrand       BrandName 
------------------------
1             Nokia
2             Samsung
3             Canon
```

Following table breaks many to many relation between Categories and Brands tables

**CategoriesBrands**

```
IdCategoriesBrand    IdCategory   IdBrand
-----------------------------------------
1                    2            1
2                    38           1
3                    115          1
4                    2            2
5                    38           2
6                    115          2
```

**Products**

```
IdProduct     Product Name       IdCategory    IdBrand
---------------------------------------------------------
1             AAAA               115           1
2             BBBB               115           2
3             CCCC               121           3
4             DDDD               115           1
5             EEEE               121           3
```

Assumption about products table

- product can be added in only third level sub-sub-category (e.g Mobile Phones, Digital Camerass)

Here are scripts to create tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [IdCategory] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,  
    [ParentCategoryId] [bigint] NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories_IdCategory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (   [IdCategory] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Brands](
    [IdBrand] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [BrandName] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Brands_IdBrand] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [IdBrand] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoriesBrands](
    [IdCategoriesBrand] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [IdCategory] [bigint] NULL,
    [IdBrand] [bigint] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CategoriesBrands] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (    [IdCategoriesBrand] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoriesBrands]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoriesBrands_Brands] FOREIGN KEY([IdBrand])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([IdBrand])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoriesBrands] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoriesBrands_Brands]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoriesBrands]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoriesBrands_Categories] FOREIGN KEY([IdCategory])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([IdCategory])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoriesBrands] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoriesBrands_Categories]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [IdProduct] [bigint]  NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [IdCategory] [bigint] NULL,
    [IdBrand] [bigint] NULL 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Products_IdProduct] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [IdProduct] ASC )
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Brands] FOREIGN KEY([IdBrand])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([IdBrand])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Brands]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Categories] FOREIGN KEY([IdCategory])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Categories] ([IdCategory])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_Categories]
GO
```

Here are scripts to insert some sample data in tables

```
INSERT INTO Categories (IdCategory, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId) VALUES(1, 'Appliances', NULL)
INSERT INTO Categories (IdCategory, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId) VALUES(2, 'Electronics', NULL)
INSERT INTO Categories (IdCategory, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId) VALUES(38, 'Phones & Mobile Devices', 2)
INSERT INTO Categories (IdCategory, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId) VALUES(39, 'Cameras & Photography', 2)
INSERT INTO Categories (IdCategory, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId) VALUES(115, 'Mobile Phones', 38)
INSERT INTO Categories (IdCategory, CategoryName, ParentCategoryId) VALUES(121, 'Digital Cameras', 39)


INSERT INTO Brands (IdBrand, BrandName) VALUES(1, 'Nokia')
INSERT INTO Brands (IdBrand, BrandName) VALUES(2, 'Samsung')
INSERT INTO Brands (IdBrand, BrandName) VALUES(3, 'Canon')


INSERT INTO CategoriesBrands (IdCategoriesBrand, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(1, 2, 1)
INSERT INTO CategoriesBrands (IdCategoriesBrand, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(2, 38, 1)
INSERT INTO CategoriesBrands (IdCategoriesBrand, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(3, 115, 1)
INSERT INTO CategoriesBrands (IdCategoriesBrand, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(4, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO CategoriesBrands (IdCategoriesBrand, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(5, 38, 2)
INSERT INTO CategoriesBrands (IdCategoriesBrand, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(6, 115, 2)


INSERT INTO Products (IdProduct, ProductName, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(1, 'AAAA', 115, 1)
INSERT INTO Products (IdProduct, ProductName, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(2, 'BBBB', 115, 2)
INSERT INTO Products (IdProduct, ProductName, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(3, 'CCCC', 121, 3)
INSERT INTO Products (IdProduct, ProductName, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(4, 'DDDD', 115, 1)
INSERT INTO Products (IdProduct, ProductName, IdCategory, IdBrand) VALUES(5, 'EEEE', 121, 3)
```

So far I have tried this which is giving me top 5 brands without category

```
SELECT TOP 5
    b1.IdBrand, 
    ISNULL(b1.BrandName, '') AS BrandName, 
    count(p.IdProduct) AS 'ProductsCount'
FROM Brands b1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products p
ON b1.IdBrand = p.IdBrand 
GROUP BY b1.IdBrand, b1.BrandName 
ORDER BY ProductsCount DESC
```

Comment: It more looks like your assignment/ homework which you have delegated here.

Comment: some scripts to create table and inserts would also be helpful - I only need ones for `Products` and `Categories`

Comment: No, this is not homework/assignment, actually i am created a consumer product reviews website and stuck on this query. Here are the full scripts you asked.

Comment: I don't see any sales or reliability data in your tables.  How can you determine the top brands?

Comment: In near future, i will add reviews table that will determine the top brands based on reviews. At the moment I want to determine based on products count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt at solving this:

- first get all the categories, starting from the root one (using a recursive CTE)
- compute brand rankings by categoryId
- for each category, display top 5 brands

I've also made an SQLFiddle where you can play around with the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8593b/12

This is the code:

```sql
declare @IdCategory bigint

set @IdCategory = 2

declare @selectedCategories
  table (IdCategory bigint primary key)


-- Use a recursive CTE to determine all
-- Categories that derive from current
-- Category
;with SelectedCategories as (
  select @IdCategory as IdCategory
  union all
  select c.IdCategory 
    from Categories c
    join SelectedCategories sc
      on sc.IdCategory = c.ParentCategoryId
)
-- Save Selected Categories
-- in a memory table
insert @selectedCategories (IdCategory)
select IdCategory from SelectedCategories

-- use another CTE to select the 
-- Brands in the Selected Categories
-- and compute their Category rank
-- using the RANK()
;with BrandsPerCategory as (
  select 
    c.IdCategory,
    cc.CategoryName,
    b.BrandName,
    rank() over (
      partition by c.IdCategory
      order by count(p.IdProduct) desc
    ) as BrandRank
  from @selectedCategories c
  join Categories cc
    on c.IdCategory = cc.IdCategory
  join CategoriesBrands cb
    on cb.IdCategory = c.IdCategory
  join Brands b
    on cb.IdBrand = b.IdBrand
  join Products p
    on p.IdBrand = b.IdBrand
  group by 
    c.IdCategory,
    cc.CategoryName,
    b.BrandName
)
select * 
from BrandsPerCategory
where BrandRank < 5
order by IdCategory, BrandRank
```

**Edit:**

If you want the top brands for all selected categories (root+subcategories), and not for each of the categories as in the example above, then you can use the following query (and [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8593b/14) SqlFiddle):

```sql
declare @IdCategory bigint

set @IdCategory = 2

-- Use a recursive CTE to determine all
-- Categories that derive from current
-- Category
;with SelectedCategories as (
  select @IdCategory as IdCategory
  union all
  select c.IdCategory 
    from Categories c
    join SelectedCategories sc
      on sc.IdCategory = c.ParentCategoryId
)
select top 5
  b.IdBrand, 
  b.BrandName,
  count(p.IdProduct) AS 'ProductsCount'
from SelectedCategories c
join Categories cc
  on c.IdCategory = cc.IdCategory
join CategoriesBrands cb
  on cb.IdCategory = c.IdCategory
join Brands b
  on cb.IdBrand = b.IdBrand
join Products p
  on p.IdBrand = b.IdBrand
GROUP BY b.IdBrand, b.BrandName 
ORDER BY ProductsCount DESC
```

**Edit 2:** *(The solution that does not multiply the number of products with the number of corresponding CategoriesBrands records)*:

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26d60/8

Code:

```sql
;with SelectedCategories as (
  select @IdCategory as IdCategory
  union all
  select c.IdCategory 
    from Categories c
    join SelectedCategories sc
      on sc.IdCategory = c.ParentCategoryId
)
select top 5
  b.IdBrand, 
  b.BrandName,
  count(p.IdProduct) AS 'ProductsCount'
from Brands b
join Products p
  on p.IdBrand = b.IdBrand
where b.IdBrand in (
  select cb.IdBrand
  from SelectedCategories c
  join CategoriesBrands cb
    on cb.IdCategory = c.IdCategory
 )
GROUP BY b.IdBrand, b.BrandName 
ORDER BY ProductsCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks alot wolf for your solutions, These are exactly what i was looking for. You saved lot of my time. I just have one confusion your second solution display productcount 6 for nokia while there are only 2 nokia products in products table. Why is that?

Comment: @Waqas good catch! That's because the 2 products have been multiplied by the number of connections Nokia has in CategoriesBrands. I'll think of a way to solve this and post an update to my answer.

Comment: @Wolf, yes now its returning correct products count. Thanks again for all the help you provided.